# appdelegate implementation in phonegap plugin

Tags: ios, phonegap-plugins

I have developed an ios application, which can run in background to fetch location data frequently. It has been implemented in such a way that core functionality is operated in the appdelegate class in 'applicationDidEnterBackground' method to fetch the location data.

Now, i need to create a phonegap plugin using this native code. And am not sure how can i include this implementation of appdelegate of that application in the plugin. I have gone through most of the tutorials for this plugin development, but i couldn't find a clue about this issue.

Does anybody know the solution?? 
Thanx in advance.